# How to implemente oauth process in a different window and then reload caller window

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to do this with a **Google App Engine application** using **OAuth 2.0** for Google Calendar's authorization (restrited to a Google Apps domain's users)

1. In case the user has not authorized the app to access his/her calendar yet, show an "authorize this app with your Google Apps account" button.
2. When the user push that button, open a new window, where the authorization process begins (the url is on the form https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=CALLER_URL&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL&response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&access_type=offline)
3. The user authorizes the app to access his/her calendar and then **this window is closed and the caller window is reloaded, to show the app**.

**Step 1** is very straightforward. **Step 2**, kind of. I can open that url in a new window, but then, the rest of the process takes place in that new window. I mean: when the user authorizes the app, then the url falls back in the callback uri, but **in the same window, not in the caller one**.

Is there any way to do this? I've seen in more sites. You push a button, a new window is opened to give the caller app authorization to access your data (Twitter account, Facebook wall, Google contacts... whatever), and then that window is closed and the caller Window reloaded, with the needed autorization token and ready to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely want it to post back to the child window. This isn't a problem because parent and child windows can communicate. So for example:

1. Some JS opens the child window and sets its location to the Google Authorization page
2. When the user accepts the dialog, the child window gets forwarded to your callback URL
3. Your server saves the token data it gets from the forwarded URL (it doesn't know or care what window the request came from)
4. The server returns a page, which gets loaded in the child window.
5. That page is blank, but contains some javascript that alerts the underlying page and closes the window

For example, the javascript might look like this:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
window.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Isaac!

I have follow this steps, but my problem is that I use @oauth2_decorator.oauth_aware python decorator, and I need change the callback URL to a specific URL because, at this moment, my app load the URL from where called it.

Is possible change the callback URL? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (particularly the part about loading the URL from where it was called), but you can change the callback URL when instantiating the decorator:  `OAuth2Decorator(callback_path='/some/path', ...)`, and then register that URL with Google in the API console.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer Isaac. You have helped me a lot!